# How can I set yarn as the default packageManager for Angular CLI? I get "Cannot read property 'value' of null"

Tags: angular, angular-cli, yarnpkg

When I run the below command

```
ng set --global packageManager=yarn
```

I get the below message

```
"get/set have been deprecated in favor of the config command"
```

and when I run ---

```
 ng config cli.packageManager yarn
```

I get the below error message

```
Cannot read property 'value' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
at ConfigCommand.set (C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\config.js:207:36)
at ConfigCommand.run (C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\config.js:181:18)
at C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js:278:30
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at fulfilled (C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js:4:58)
at <anonymous>
```

How can I resolve this?

Below is the version information
I am using Java 8.

```
NPM version - 5.6.0
Yarn version --1.7.0
```

ng - v  gives me the following result. I want to use Angular js

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 8.11.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.6.8
@schematics/angular          0.6.8
@schematics/update           0.6.8
rxjs                         6.2.1
typescript                   2.7.2
```

Comment: You said that you want to use Angular js - this is commonly what angular 1 is called, is this what you are trying to do? The angular CLI will not build with that version of angular

Answer (score 13):

If you want to set this globally, use this instead:  `ng config -g cli.packageManager yarn`
If you are trying to set it locally you have a bit of a problem in that `ng new` builds your package for you, until you have done this you do not have a local package to configure.

-- Update --

[As of Angular 11](https://angular.io/cli/new), the Angular CLI team added a new flag to pick the package manager `--package-manager` which can be set to `npm|yarn|pnpm|cnpm`. This means you can set the package manager when you create a new project with a command that would look something like:
`ng new projectName --package-manager=yarn`

Comment: Angular 17.2 adds support for Bun as well

Answer (score 1):

Just enter the command when you create the project `ng new my_app --package-manager=yarn`